# Least $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{|n|} = \aleph_0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

It is well known that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$. This seems to imply that there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{|n|} = \aleph_0$. If so, what is known about the least permitted value of $n$ such that this statement is true?

Comment: If you undelete your question I will be able to show you the most elementary way https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118937/must-the-analytic-continuation-of-zetas-for-s-in-mathbbc-backslash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that $2^\kappa = \aleph_0$ has no solution $\kappa$ in cardinal numbers.

As you say, $2^{\aleph_0} \gt \aleph_0$ by Cantor's Thm., and exponentiation of cardinals is monotonic.  So the only possibility is that $\kappa$ is less than $\aleph_0$.

But such $\kappa$ would be finite (since $\aleph_0$ is the least infinite cardinal), and then $2^\kappa$ would also be finite (not $\aleph_0$).

Answer (score 5):

No, $2^n$ is finite for all $n\in \mathbb N$ while $\aleph_0$ is an infinite cardinal.

Comment: Does this not make the function $2^{|n|}$ discontinuous, jumping from a finite cardinal to $2^{\aleph_0}$ as $n$ transitions from finite to infinite? It seems as though one "skips" over a cardinality of $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Well, it skips lots of finite values as well e.g. $3, 5, 6, 7, 9$.  All except powers of $2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is finite then $2^n$ will be as well.

See [logarithms of cardinal numbers at Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Logarithms) for more details.

Is this unintuitive?  Maybe, maybe not, intuition does not work well with infinite cardinals.  I don't see that it is unintuitive but opinions may vary.  $2^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ skips many finite values as well e.g. $2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9$.